# App won't recognize swipes using Hammer.JS and HammerGestureConfig in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, swipe, hammer.js, angular9

I can't recognize swipes in my Angular app using Hammer.JS. It's setup like this:

```
"@angular/core": "~9.0.0-next.6",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

**app.module.ts** is looking like this:

```
import { BrowserModule, HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as hammer from 'hammerjs';

export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = <any>{
    swipe: { direction: hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL },
    pinch: { enable: false },
    rotate: { enable: false }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: MyHammerConfig
    }
  ],
})
```

**app.component.ts** has this method:

```
onSwipe() {
  console.log('swipe');
}
```

And finaly **app.component.html** looks like this:

```
<div (swipeleft)="onSwipe()" (swiperight)="onSwipe()">
  <h1>Swipe here</h1>
</div>
```

However, neither `swipeleft` or `swiperight` are triggered ever using an iPad or iPhone both running iOS 13.

*Am I missing any crucial configuration? Or do I have another issue with this code?*

---

I also tested this [Stackblitz "blog-ng-swiping"](https://stackblitz.com/edit/blog-ng-swiping) which is working fine on the touch devices, but it's using Angular 8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turns out that Angular 9 has a new [`HammerModule`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/HammerModule) which is used for everything Hammer.JS related and also for tree shaking during compilation.

So besides the whole configuratonion of Hammer.JS, gestures etc. you need to include this Module in your app as well to make Hammer.JS work with Angular 9:

```
import { HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HammerModule
  ]
)}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! <3

Comment: I spent 2 hours trying to figure out this on my own. I should have seen this before, Thanks!